# How do I delete a file from the File System view in a VS 2010 Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I made a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010. I then accidentially added a bunch of files to "User's Programs Menu" under the File System viewer. I'd like to delete the files, but the Delete menu item is disabled. Aside from deleting the entire setup project and starting from scratch, is there any way to remove the items I accidentially added?

[image: Dropdown menu for deleting files from File System View]

Comment: Are you sure they are not dependencies of another file in the install?

Comment: I'm sure they are dependencies. They're already set to be installed in the Application Folder. I just don't want them installed in User's Programs Menu as well.

Comment: I'm lost. Why are any of them in User's Programs Menu? That's where you put shortcuts, not files. The files go (usually) into "Application Folder"

Comment: @PhilDW - Exactly. It was a mistake--I accidentally put the files into User's Programs Menu. Now I'm trying to undo what I did.